# ssl class 1 certificate problem

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

my android give me an error about the certificate.
is it a problem coz im using ssl class 1 from startssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, some certificates don't validate on Android.
From my experience, **PositiveSSL** (Comodo) doesn't work. What works is **RapidSSL**.

Comment: RapidSSL is not working on my Android 2.2, see also: https://support.servertastic.com/entries/426677-rapidssl-and-geotrust-certificate-not-trusted-on-mobile-device

Comment: Above link has changed. Information regarding RapidSSL function with Android and the need for a cross root cert is available here: https://support.servertastic.com/rapidssl-and-geotrust-certificate-not-trusted-on-mobile-device/